# Zooming into center of map on load of ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: zoom, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I was looking through the ArcGIS code samples and I found [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-layers/index.html). I really like the way that it zooms in from afar, but I can't seem to figure out how to fly in to the location on load like this version does.

Can anyone help me figure out what lines drive this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't debugged it but I believe lines 103 to 107, specifically line 105.

```
view.goTo(housingLyr.fullExtent);
```

This Navigates the scene objects to the extent of the housing layer. Looking at the source code it looks like there is listener set to listen for when the scene is loaded, then a listener is set for when the population layer is loaded and then zoom to the population layer extent.

Source code in the [sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=get-started-layers)

Comment: This worked. All I had to do was create my own JSON object with an ID, title, and then fullExtent containing Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax, and zoom range and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you!